# Unable to insert data in mysql database using JDBC in Netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, netbeans

I used it inside the button action made database, even connected the database but the information is not going inside the table of the data base.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhoast:3306//a","root","root");
        Statement smt = conn.createStatement();
        ps = conn.prepareStatement("insert into aone values (?,?,?)");

        String n = name.getText();
        String a = age.getText();
        String r = roll.getText();

        ps.setString(1,n);
        ps.setString(2,a);
        ps.setString(3,r);

        int i = ps.executeUpdate();

        if (i>0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "data is saved");
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error");
        }           
    }

    catch(Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: How do you determine that it is not in the db. Be more specific and ask concrete questions.

Answer (score 1):

Print the stack trace in the catch block. The JVM might be throwing an exception, but you'll never know it this way.

When you do that, I'm sure you'll be told that JDBC could not connect to "localhoast".

I doubt that "localhoast" is correct; try "localhost".

There are so many things wrong with this code:

1. Should not mingle UI and database code.
2. Should not get JDBC connection with every request; use a pool.
3. Code is not layered; hard to test.
4. You don't close any JDBC resources in method scope.

Try it like this:

```
    private void jButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn =         DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/a","root","root");
            ps = conn.prepareStatement("insert into aone values (?,?,?)");

            String n = name.getText();
            String a = age.getText();
            String r = roll.getText();

            ps.setString(1,n);
            ps.setString(2,a);
            ps.setString(3,r);

            int i = ps.executeUpdate();

            if (i > 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "data is saved");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error");
            }           
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            close(ps);  // You need to implement this
            close(conn); // You need to implement this
        }
    }
```

Comment: To top it all, the database name `a` is behind two forward slashes `/`, which won't work - Connection string is wrong!

Comment: Sorry, I meant in the OP's question!

Comment: Should just be one Unix slash.  I fixed it in my code, but not in his.